Tkinter and matplotlib - automatically resize canvas size when window size changes (maximizes)
I created a small tool where various data is displayed in a plot. I use tight_layout() to save space in the GUI. Minimum example is shown below.
I'm aware, that I have to call tight_layout() each time, the main window size (canvas size) changes. This is properly working with the code below if the window is manually resized. The only issue I have is, if the window is maximized. For me it looks like tight_layout() is somehow executed before the new widht/height is applied and after maximizing the window, I have a huge white area around the plot. If the window then is "unmaximized" again, the figure is too big and partially cut by the window itself.
Is there any recommendation, that this code also works if the main window is maximized?
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

class guiPlotarea(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, main):
        super(guiPlotarea, self).__init__()
        self.master = master
        
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6), dpi=100)
        self.ax = plt.subplot(111)
        self.ax.set(xlabel='f in MHz', ylabel='dBµV/m')
        self.ax.grid()
        self.fig.tight_layout()
        self.ax.grid(True, which='minor', linestyle = ':')

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.width = 1400
        self.master.height = 830
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)    # left column for plot and data on the bottom
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)       # upper row for plot
        self.initGUI()
        
    def initGUI(self):
        self.master.plotarea = guiPlotarea(self.master, self)
        self.master.plotarea.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='wens')
        self.master.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
        
    def resize(self,event):
        if event.widget == self.master:
            if (self.master.width != event.width) | (self.master.height != event.height):
                self.master.width = event.width
                self.master.height = event.height
                self.master.plotarea.fig.tight_layout()

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()


edit:
I played around a little bit more and I had the idea to use tk.IntVar() for my width and height value and then trace these two values. The behavior of the tool did not change. Still, if the user maximizes the tight_layout() is not applied as expected from me. Here is the modified code:
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

class guiPlotarea(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, main):
        super(guiPlotarea, self).__init__()
        self.master = master
        
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6), dpi=100)
        self.ax = plt.subplot(111)
        self.ax.set(xlabel='f in MHz', ylabel='dBµV/m')
        self.ax.grid()
        self.fig.tight_layout()
        self.ax.grid(True, which='minor', linestyle = ':')

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.width = tk.IntVar()
        self.master.height = tk.IntVar()
        self.master.width.set(1400)
        self.master.height.set(830)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)    # left column for plot and data on the bottom
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)       # upper row for plot
        self.initGUI()
        self.master.width.trace('w',self.resize2)
        self.master.height.trace('w',self.resize2)
        
    def initGUI(self):
        self.master.plotarea = guiPlotarea(self.master, self)
        self.master.plotarea.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='wens')
        self.master.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
        
    def resize(self,event):
        if event.widget == self.master:
            if (self.master.width.get() != event.width) | (self.master.height.get() != event.height):
                self.master.width.set(event.width)
                self.master.height.set(event.height)
                # self.master.plotarea.fig.tight_layout()
    
    def resize2(self,a,b,c):
        self.master.plotarea.fig.tight_layout()
        
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()


The FigureCanvasTkAgg class is a subclass of the FigureCanvasTk class, which already has a resizing function bound to the "" event. The size of the canvas and the figure changes without a special function. I ran the first version of your code with matplotlib v3.7.0 and it resizes. The issue is when the window is too small, then the labels are not visible. You need to set a minimum root window size.

You are currently using the following geometry management combination that triggers the event: self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True) + self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1), self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) + self.master.plotarea.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='wens').
